# Assalamualaikum I have a doubt I promise in Quran I will not masturburate so I can’t control and I started masturburating daily do allah forgive me

Tags: sex

Can I daily mastaburating when allah forgive like before or not
What should I do
And can’t give
Food or money for poor people beacause I am just 13 year and I don’t have my own money

Please tell me

Inshallah ...

Answer (score 1):

Al Salam alaykum wa Rahmut Allah brother. First of all, I would like to commend you for your sincerity and effort to quit a sinful act like masturbating, especially at such a young age, Masha Allah; this shows your fear of Allah The All-Mighty!

Now regarding promising/taking an oath on the Holy Quran and then breaking that promise/oath, that act is considered a sin because you broke and did not fulfill your promise with God, so now you have to **first**: feed or clothe ten poor people. However, if you **can't**, then you have to fast for three days in order to repent from this sin.

And finally, my brother, try not to promise on the Holy Quran next time, but try your best to quit this act and always seek repentance and remember that Allah is always Watching you.